# How to flush side-aligned images before the end of an h3 section?

Tags: html, wordpress, alignment

I am preparing in html a post that will be published in a wordpress website, with a lot of right-aligned images. I'd like the images to appear within the `<h3>` section where they are inserted, that is, that the following `<h3>` title is always below an image whose code is inserted above.

```html
<h3>Section One with image</h3>
<img src="image-not-found.jpg" align="right" width="50%" />
Text here is short.
<h3>Section Two without image</h3>
```

I have tried surrounding the `<img>` tag with `<p>` or `<div>` but this doesn't prevent the following `<h3>` title to be side-by-side with image.

Is there a way in HTML to request that all images be flushed before displaying further text?

Note that I do not have admin rights on the wordpress site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a quick and dirty hack for this.

Before the `<h3>` tag, insert a placeholder image of 100% width and zero or 1 height:

```
<img src="notfound.png" width="100%" height="0">
```

I am not sure how robust that is.